# QuickBooks Authentication error when getting basic company information

Tags: quickbooks, quickbooks-online

I'm writing a simple desktop application to get information from QuickBooks(*developer account using demo account(UK) data*) and in this regard I've been able to go past the OAuth flow. However, I've not been able to get the basic company information

The below is a capture of the Fiddler request and response:

```
GET https://quickbooks.api.intuit.com/v3/company/123145829830639/companyInfo/123145829830639 HTTP/1.1
Authorization:  oauth_token="****", oauth_nonce="z4x0a196", oauth_consumer_key="****", oauth_signature_method="HMAC-SHA1", oauth_timestamp="1499283607", oauth_version="1.0", oauth_signature="EGw6Ty%2BKFAawrH1%2FSxQuFwaMcEo%3D"
Content-Type: application/json
Host: quickbooks.api.intuit.com
```

The generation of the header is similar to https://developer.intuit.com/v2/apiexplorer?apiname=V3QBO#?id=CompanyInfo but I end up getting the following response(Fiddler partial response) based on the request

```
intuit_tid: gw-c4e19f89-df78-42a5-ae7e-216187421143
Set-Cookie: JSESSIONID=21BF1FFEE48B39538E82485FD25C4280.c51-pprdsbxas901; Path=/; Secure; HttpOnly
QBO-Version: 1706.912
ErrorCode: 100
ErrorCause: AuthenticationErrorGeneral: SRV-110-Authentication Failure ,   statusCode: 401
Message: General Authentication Error
```

The code to access company information is as below:

```
 string companyInfo = String.Format("company/{0}/companyInfo/{0}", authenticator.OAuthProfile.realmId);
 string  ciUrl = BASE_URL + companyInfo; //https://quickbooks.api.intuit.com/v3/
 var sb = new System.Text.StringBuilder();
 sb.AppendFormat("oauth_token=\"{0}\", oauth_nonce=\"{1}\", oauth_consumer_key=\"{2}\", oauth_signature_method=\"HMAC-SHA1\", oauth_timestamp=\"{3}\", oauth_version=\"1.0\", oauth_signature=\"{4}\"",
                    Manager.UrlEncode(_token),
                    Manager.UrlEncode(_nonce),
                    Manager.UrlEncode(_consumer_key),
                    Manager.UrlEncode(_timestamp),
                    Manager.UrlEncode(_signature));
 var authorisationHeader = sb.ToString().TrimEnd(' ').TrimEnd(',');


 // Request Company Information
 var request = (System.Net.HttpWebRequest)System.Net.WebRequest.Create(ciUrl);
 request.Headers.Add("Authorization", authorisationHeader);
 request.Method = "GET";
 request.ContentType = "application/json";
 using (var response = (System.Net.HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse())
 {
       // get 401
 }
```

**Used sandbox URL and added minorversion to the base URL**
I attempted setting  BASE_URL set to the sandbox url(https://sandbox-quickbooks.api.intuit.com/v3) and also set *minorversion* to be 4.

Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Hopefully this helps, but here is a Java snippet using their SDK that works for me:

```
   OAuthAuthorizer oauth = new OAuthAuthorizer(System.env.QB_OAUTH_CONSUMER_KEY, System.env.QB_OAUTH_CONSUMER_SECRET,
            vendor.intuitOAuthAccessToken, vendor.intuitOAuthAccessSecret);

    UUID trackingID = UUID.randomUUID()


    log.info("About to init Context companyID=" + vendor.realmId + ", app_token=" + System.env.QB_APP_TOKEN + ", uuid=" + trackingID.toString())

    Context context = new Context(oauth, System.env.QB_APP_TOKEN, ServiceType.QBO, vendor.realmId)
    context.setMinorVersion("4")

    context.setTrackingID(trackingID)

    log.info("About to set BaseURL")

    Config.setProperty(Config.BASE_URL_QBO, System.env.QB_BASE_URL + "/v3/company");



    log.info("About to init DataService")

    // get all customers
    log.info("About to executeQuery")
    DataService service = new DataService(context)
    QueryResult queryResult = service.executeQuery("select * from customer");
```

In my case, QB_BASE_URL=https://sandbox-quickbooks.api.intuit.com
*NOTE there isn't a trailing slash

vendor.intuitOAuthAccessToken and vendor.intuitOAuthAccessSecret are the values you get back after the oauth flow